# Play and wait for audio to finish playing

Tags: c#, audio, triggers, unity-game-engine

in my project I want a sound to play and then for an objects active state to be set to false, at the moment both are happening at the same time so the sound doesn't play. If I keep the active state as true then I will hear the sound play.

How can I make sure that the audio finishes before the set active state is switched to false, any help or advice is appreciated.

Here's a selection of my code;

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.tag == "Pick Up") 
     {
         if (!isPlayed) {
             source.Play ();
             isPlayed = true;
         }
     }
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up"))
     {
         other.gameObject.SetActive (true);
         count = count + 1;
         SetCountText ();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Audio Source has a `isPlaying` field that you can check. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, it's a case where you have to wait in a coroutine on .isPlaying - just like with animations.

Comment: @JoeBlow he has to do that in a coroutine or have lots of bool on the update function. coroutine is the way to do this.

Comment: right on .........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use coroutine as Joe Said. Start coroutine each time the collided object is enabled.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.tag == "Pick Up") 
     {
         if (!isPlayed) {
             source.Play ();
             isPlayed = true;
         }
     }
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up"))
     {
         other.gameObject.SetActive (true);
         count = count + 1;
         SetCountText ();
         StartCoroutine(waitForSound(other)); //Start Coroutine
     }
 }



 IEnumerator waitForSound(Collider other)
    {
        //Wait Until Sound has finished playing
        while (source.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

       //Auidio has finished playing, disable GameObject
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could hide the object using its `renderer`, as well as turning off any colliders, play the sound, then destroy/set it to inactive:

```
renderer.enabled = false;
gameObject.collider.enabled = false;

audio.PlayOneShot(someAudioClip);
Destroy(gameObject, someAudioClip.length); //wait until the audio has finished playing before destroying the gameobject
// Or set it to inactive
```

Answer (score 1):

Many posts indicate issues with using WaitForSeconds as well as WaitWhile(AudioSource.isPlaying) giving incorrect values if the clip is paused, game loses focus, or if the pitch of the audio is altered.

So I believe I've found a better solution:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Pick Up") 
    {
        if (!isPlayed) 
        {
            source.Play ();
            isPlayed = true;
        }
    }
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText ();
        StartCoroutine(waitForSound(other)); //Start Coroutine
    }
}

private IEnumerator PlayAudioAndDeactivate(Collider other)
{
    audioSource.clip = clip;
    audioSource.Play();
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => audioSource.time >= clip.length);
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false); //Whatever it is that you're wanting to do.
}
```

By using the AudioSource.time and AudioClip.length you're comparing the playback position to the length of the clip, which should always be correct. I have tested this successfully with pauses and pitch changes.