# How to play a sound once or till the animation ends?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I attached a sound clip to my object walk function, but when my object stops the sound keeps running. I'm using the `PlayOneShot` function but the sound plays 3 or 4 secound more than the animation. The sound is mixed with itself also.

```
if (JSMove.x != 0.0f) { 
   transform.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("maleWalk");           
   audio.PlayOneShot(WalkSound, 0.5f); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet, so we can help you?

Comment: here JSMove is my input and all the code is in Update function

Comment: when  x value is not equal to zero for some time the audio plays again and again also overlap or mix with the first audio sound , i just want  that when one audio plays the other audio shell not be played

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah - do you understand this basic principal: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36134976/294884  it is very common in Unity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark's answer fixes partially the problem: while the animation is running the sound would be played over and over again. So you have to check if the sound is still running before playing it again.

```
if (JSMove.x != 0.0f) {
   transform.GetComponent().Play("maleWalk");
   if (!audio.isPlaying)
     audio.PlayOneShot(WalkSound, 0.5f);
} else if (audio.isPlaying)
   audio.Stop();
```

Comment: i just want exactly let the previously started' audioclip complete play and finish playback.then the other audioclip plays

Answer (score 0):

[PlayOneShot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) is to play an audio clip, it won't stop playback before the 'walksound' is over.
Without the code you resist to submit, I can give you a generic answer which is, your code should be something like:

```
if (JSMove.x != 0.0f) {
transform.GetComponent().Play("maleWalk");
audio.PlayOneShot(WalkSound,0.5f);
} else if (audio.isPlaying) { //no movement yet audio did not finish the clip
audio.Stop();
}
```

The "mixover" you mention is because the clip is still playing when you try to start over and play it again. You either should stop playback before you start again, or, depending on your game's needs, don't start playing the clip again (i.e. let the 'previously started' audioclip finish playback).

Comment: how to let the previously started' audioclip finish playback

Comment: i just want exactly let the previously started' audioclip finish playback.then the other audioclip plays.

Comment: Same things to use as what I wrote above. If JSMove.x > 0.0f and audio.isPlaying, don't play. if JSMove.x still > 0.0f, but audio.isPlaying is false, start playing the audio. That simple ;)