# Build a SceneFader in Unity, Make methods wait for the previous call to finish

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait

i built my own SceneFader in Unity. I achieve this by making the Color of the camera darker or brighter.

The Code:

```
public class SceneFader : MonoBehaviour {

float lerpSpeed = 1; // Speed of the Change of the Colors

internal Camera GetCamera() // Get the current camera of the scene
{
    return GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
}

internal void SceneFadeIn(Camera camera, Color defaultColor, Color sceneChangeColor) // Is called at the new scene
{
    camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(sceneChangeColor, defaultColor, lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

internal void SceneFadeOut(Camera camera, Color defaultColor, Color sceneChangeColor) // Is called at the previous scene
{
    camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(defaultColor, sceneChangeColor, lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

So when a scene changes, i use this Code:

```
        public class SceneController : SceneFader {

        internal void LoadScene(string sceneName) // name of the Scene to load
        {
         SceneFadeOut(GetCamera(), Color.black, GetCamera().backgroundColor); // go darker 
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName); // load the new scene
             SceneFadeIn(GetCamera(), GetCamera().backgroundColor, Color.black); // go brighter 
        }
    }
```

My question is, how can i make the 3 Methodes wait for each other to finish? The scene should be loaded when the color is a dark one, not before.

Does someone knows?

Comment: hey peter, you need to check out the basics of coroutines, which is how you access the frames in Unity. you can find millions of examples here ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36134976/294884  Unless I misunderstand you, that's all you need - cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean that, once it has reached it's maximum/minimum (Which are 255 and 0, respectively) should set the boolean to true.

And then an if-statement to check if the boolean is true.

Comment: But if I do so, the method would leave the method after the first task, no? Because the second one cant be done, because the bool is false. So I need something to wait for it ...

Comment: It's been a while since I've been using Unity,
But so far I know, a method is continiously entering and leaving every frame.

Try validating the booleans where you've placed the lerpspeed.
And then let a boolean change once the color has become the color you wanted.

Then call another method whithin the other method. 

Once again, I havn't been looking for Unity for a while, so I may have given the wrong answer, but it's worth the try.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Coroutines. You can do something like this to load your level :

```
public class SceneController : SceneFader
{
    internal void LoadScene(string sceneName) // name of the Scene to load
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadSceneCoroutine(sceneName));
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadSceneCoroutine(string sceneName)
    {
        float lerpTimer = 0.0f;
        while (lerpTimer < base.lerpDuration)
        {
            lerpTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            SceneFadeOut(GetCamera(), Color.black, GetCamera().backgroundColor, lerpTimer / base.lerpDuration);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        SceneFadeOut(GetCamera(), Color.black, GetCamera().backgroundColor, 1.0f);

        AsyncOperation m_AsyncOp = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName); // load the new scene
        yield return m_AsyncOp;

        lerpTimer = 0.0f;
        while (lerpTimer < base.lerpDuration)
        {
            lerpTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            SceneFadeIn(GetCamera(), Color.black, GetCamera().backgroundColor, lerpTimer / base.lerpDuration);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        SceneFadeOut(GetCamera(), GetCamera().backgroundColor, Color.black, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

And in your **SceneFader** class :

```
public class SceneFader : MonoBehaviour
{
    //WARNING : I changed this parameter name for better understanding
    float lerpDuration = 1; // Time of the Change of the Colors

    void Start()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    internal Camera GetCamera() // Get the current camera of the scene
    {
        return GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    internal void SceneFadeIn(Camera camera, Color defaultColor, Color sceneChangeColor, float lerpValue) // Is called at the new scene
    {
        camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(sceneChangeColor, defaultColor, lerpValue);
    }

    internal void SceneFadeOut(Camera camera, Color defaultColor, Color sceneChangeColor, float lerpValue) // Is called at the previous scene
    {
        camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(defaultColor, sceneChangeColor, lerpValue);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try this out :) but at first, i try to use this here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html

Answer (score 0):

So when you have used the method "WaitUntil()" as written on https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html, how to use it?
I really don't get it when there is no time to check.

Let's say you have this pseudo code:

```
bool finishedFadeOut = false; // can start loading a new scene?
bool finishedLoading = false; // can start fading in?

internal void LoadScene(string sceneName) // pass in the scene to load
{
    SceneFade(GetCamera(), GetCamera().backgroundColor, Color.black); // fade out
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName); // load the scene
    SceneFade(GetCamera(), Color.black, GetCamera().backgroundColor); // fade in

    StartCoroutine(ManageScene()); // start the coroutine
}

IEnumerator ManageScene()
{
    ...
    yield return new WaitUntil(); // wait for ... ?
}

private void Update()
{
    if (...) // missing part
    {
        finishedFadeOut = true; // can start to load a new scene
    }
    if (...) // missing part
    {
        finishedLoading = true; // can start to fade in the scene
    }
}
```

What would be needed to make it work =?

Would be nice if someone could explain the missing parts!